# getelemenById('...').click doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getelementbyid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [innerDocument.getElementById(<elment ID>).click(); doesn't work in Firefox/chrome, in IE it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468864/innerdocument-getelementbyidelment-id-click-doesnt-work-in-firefox-chrom)

I have a tabbed html page.

```
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab1" id='accomodation'>Accomodation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" id='relaxation'>Relaxation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3" id='recreation'>Recreation</a></li>
                  </ul>
```

I come from another html with click and I want to show the tab regarding what I clicked earlier (I store it in a cookie).

Therefore I added IDs for the tabs and when this page loads I call a function which reads the ID from the cookie and then click the regarding tab. The function runs when the page loads:

```
<body onLoad="where_from();">
```

Here is the function:

```
function where_from()
{
    if (readCookie('came_from')!="false")
    {
        pos=readCookie('came_from');
        if (pos=='relaxation')
            document.getElementById('relaxation').click();

        if (pos=='recreation')
            document.getElementById('recreation').click();
}
```

}

It works perfect in IE and Firefox but nothing happens in Chrome

Can anyone help what's wrong?

I  have the feeling that something wrong around the getelementById.click call, but I couldn't find any solution described here.

Please help!!

Comment: It's pretty well established that document.getElementById works in chrome, so it must be something to do with the click. When you click on one of the list items, what happens? Is another JS function called, and if so, can you just call it at this stage, rather than simulating a click on the element.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not support `click()` on elements. You can implement it like this:

```
if( !document.body.click) {
    HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
        var t = this;
        do {
            if( t.onclick) t.onclick();
            t = t.parentNode;
        } while (t);
    }
}
```

It's only an approximation, as it won't handle the Event object correctly, but for the most part this should work reasonably well.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a pro, so where should I put this?

Comment: Anywhere before the code that tries to call `click()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to click tabs link to change page.

you can do it with `document.location.href`,

```
function where_from()
{
    if (readCookie('came_from')!="false")
    {
        pos=readCookie('came_from');
        if (pos=='relaxation')
            document.location.href = document.getElementById('relaxation').href;

        if (pos=='recreation')
            document.location.href = document.getElementById('recreation').href;
     }
}
```

[here is a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/S6Wtg/), that is copied from [here](http://blixt.org/media/a/1/tabs-js/page.html#page=page-3).

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work at all. It won't jump to the tab.

Comment: @MarcellJarvas Is it possible to see your whole code, there should be another problem in your code, if I see your code, I can try to write a jquery or only javascript function to solve your problem.

Comment: Thx, but Dan Prince was right, there is another JS called then (when page loads or tab clicked).

Comment: So I solved the problem without using click event. I just simply modified the other JS to show the regarding tab. But thx for all who tried to help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if  `document.getElementById('relaxation').click();` is not working , this might work for you : `$('#relaxation').click();`

ex:

```
$('#relaxation').click(function(){

//Onclick do something

});
```

To download Jquery support Files visit  : http://jquery.com/

Comment: This won't work in every webpage, they need jQuery.

Comment: This one also doesn't work, although I have jQuery-1.4.2 included in the header.

Comment: this doesn't work, because you can't do a user click with `$('#relaxation').click()`, it works only click events that you create after in jquery/javascript.